# Call to undefined method Xml::toString()

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, plugins

I am integrating freshbooks plugin in cakePHP, I am getting above issue as: `

```
Call to undefined method Xml::toString()`
```

My Code in Datasource ->FreshBooksSource.php

```
  App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
class FreshbookSource extends DataSource {

/**
 * description
 * @var string
 */
    public $description = 'Freshbooks DataSource';

/**
 * config
 * @var array
 */
    public $config = array(
        'subdomain' => '',
        'token' => '',
        /**
         * cache
         * true = use freshbooks cache
         * false = disable cache
         * 'cache-name' = cache config to use
         */
        'cache' => true,
    );

/**
 * http
 * @var object
 */
    public $http = null;

/**
 * url
 * @var string
 */
    public $url = null;

/**
 * __requestXml
 * Stores the last sent xml string
 * @var string
 */
    private $__requestXml = null;

/**
 * __responseXml
 * Stores the last received xml string
 * @var string
 */
    private $__responseXml = null;

/**
 * __construct
 * @param array $config
 */
    public function __construct($config) {
        $this->init($config);
        parent::__construct($config);

    }

/**
 * init
 * Inits the socket, url and cache.
 *
 * @param array $config
 * @return bool
 */
    public function init($config=null) {
        $this->config = array_merge($this->config, (array)$config);
        if (!class_exists('HttpSocket') || !class_exists('Xml')) {
            App::import('Core', array('HttpSocket', 'Xml'));
        }
        $this->http = new HttpSocket();
        $this->url = 'https://'.$this->config['subdomain'].'.freshbooks.com/api/2.1/xml-in';
        if ($this->config['cache'] === true) {
            Cache::config('freshbooks', array('engine'=> 'File', 'prefix' => 'freshbooks_'));
            $this->config['cache'] = 'freshbooks';
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * read
 * Handles list and get sub methods.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param object $model
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
    public function read(&$model, $data=array()) {
        $method = (isset($model->method)) ? $model->method : Inflector::underscore($model->alias);
        $params = array();
        if (isset($data['conditions'][$model->alias.'.'.$model->primaryKey])) {
            $model->id = $data['conditions'][$model->alias.'.'.$model->primaryKey];
        }
        if (isset($data['conditions'][$model->primaryKey])) {
            $model->id = $data['conditions'][$model->primaryKey];
        }
        if ($model->id !== false) {
            $submethod = 'get';
            $params[$model->primaryKey] = $model->id;
        } else {
            $submethod = 'list';
            $params['per_page'] = (!empty($data['limit'])) ? $data['limit'] : 100;
            $params['page'] = (!empty($data['page'])) ? $data['page'] : 1;
            $params = Set::merge((array)$data['conditions'], $params);
        }
        $hash = $method.'_'.$submethod.'_'.implode('_', array_merge(array_keys($params), array_values($params)));
        $hash = hash('md4', $hash);
        if (($res = Cache::read($hash, $this->config['cache'])) === false || $this->config['cache'] === false) {
            $params = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return array($a);'), $params);
            $xml =& new Xml(array('Request' => array('method' => $method.'.'.$submethod)+$params));
            $this->__requestXml = $xml->toString(array('header' => true));
            $res = $this->_parseResponse(
                $this->http->get($this->url, null, array_merge(
                    $this->__getAuthArray(),
                    array('body' => $this->__requestXml)
                )
            ));
            if ($this->config['cache'] !== false) {
                if (isset($model->cache)) {
                    Cache::set($model->cache);
                }
                Cache::write($hash, $res, $this->config['cache']);
            }
        }
        if ($res === false) {
            return array();
        }
        $findTable = Inflector::camelize($model->useTable);
        $findAlias = $model->alias;
        if ($data['fields'] == 'count') {
            if ($submethod == 'get') {
                $res = array(array(array('count' => 1)));
            } else {
                $res = array(array(array('count' => current(Set::extract('/Response/'.$findTable.'/total', $res)))));
            }
        } elseif ($submethod == 'get') {
            $this->_formatResponse($res);
            $res = array(array($model->alias => current(Set::extract('/Response/'.$findAlias.'/.', $res))));
        } else {
            $this->_formatResponse($res, 3);
            // MEH, ALMOST A HACKLESS DATASOURCE
            if ($model->alias == 'Staff') {
                $res = Set::extract('/Response/'.$findTable.'/Member', $res, array('flatten' => false));
                foreach ($res as $key => $val) {
                    $res[$key]['Staff'] = $val['Member'];
                    unset($res[$key]['Member']);
                }
            } else {
                $res = Set::extract('/Response/'.$findTable.'/'.$findAlias, $res, array('flatten' => false));
            }
        }
        return $res;
    }

/**
 * query
 * Give outside access to things in datasource.
 *
 * @param string $query
 * @param array $data
 * @param object $model
 * @return mixed
 */
    public function query($query=null, $data=null, &$model=null) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($query), 'findby') === 0) {
            $field = Inflector::underscore(preg_replace('/^findBy/i', '', $query));
            if ($field == 'id') {
                $field = $model->primaryKey;
            }
            return $model->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    $field => current($data),
                ),
            ));
        }
        if (strtolower($query) == 'freshbooks') {
            $this->__requestXml = current($data);
            $res = $this->_parseResponse(
                $this->http->get($this->url, null, array_merge(
                    $this->__getAuthArray(),
                    array('body' => $this->__requestXml)
                )
            ));
            if ($res === false) {
                return false;
            }
            $this->_formatResponse($res);
            return $res;
        }
        if (strtolower($query) == 'requestxml') {
            return $this->__requestXml;
        }
        if (strtolower($query) == 'responsexml') {
            return $this->__responseXml;
        }
        throw new Exception(__d('freshbooks', 'Sorry, that find method is not supported.', true));
    }

/**
 * create
 * Handles create and update sub methods.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param object $model
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $values
 * @return boolean
 */
    public function create(&$model, $fields=null, $values=null) {
        $method = (isset($model->method)) ? $model->method : Inflector::underscore($model->alias);
        $data = array_combine((array)$fields, (array)$values);
        if (isset($data[$model->primaryKey])) {
            $model->id = $data[$model->primaryKey];
            unset($data[$model->primaryKey]);
        }
        if ($model->id !== false) {
            $submethod = 'update';
            $data[$model->primaryKey] = $model->id;
        } else {
            $submethod = 'create';
        }
        $xml =& new Xml(array('Request' => array('method' => $method.'.'.$submethod)));
        $node =& new Xml(array($method => array()));
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $singular = Inflector::singularize($key);
                $val = array($key => array($singular => $val));
                @$node->first()->append($val, array('format' => 'tags'));
                unset($data[$key]);
            } elseif (substr($val, 0, 1) == '<') {
                $my_node =& new Xml($val);
                @$node->first()->append($my_node->children);
                unset($data[$key]);
            } else {
                $my = array($key => array(array($val)));
                @$node->first()->append($my);
            }
        }
        $xml->first()->append($node->children);
        $this->__requestXml = $xml->toString(array('header' => true));
        $res = $this->_parseResponse(
            $this->http->get($this->url, null, array_merge(
                $this->__getAuthArray(),
                array('body' => $this->__requestXml)
            )
        ));
        if ($res === false) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($submethod == 'create') {
            $model->id = current(Set::extract('/Response/'.$model->primaryKey, $res));
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * update
 * Alias for create.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param object $model
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $values
 * @return boolean
 */
    public function update(&$model, $fields=null, $values=null) {
        return $this->create($model, $fields, $values);
    }

/**
 * delete
 *
 * @access public
 * @param object $model
 * @param integer $id
 * @return boolean
 */
    public function delete(&$model, $id=null) {
        if ($id == null) {
            $id = $model->id;
            if ($id === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $method = (isset($model->method)) ? $model->method : Inflector::underscore($model->alias);
        $xml =& new Xml(array('Request' => array('method' => $method.'.delete', $model->primaryKey => array($id))));
        $req = $xml->toString(array('header' => true));
        $res = $this->_parseResponse(
            $this->http->get($this->url, null, array_merge(
                $this->__getAuthArray(),
                array('body' => $req)
            )
        ));
        if ($res === false) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * _parseResponse
 * Either returns response as array or throws error.
 *
 * @param string $response
 * @return array
 */
    protected function _parseResponse($response=null) {
        if (empty($response)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->__responseXml = $response;
        $xml =& new Xml($response);
        $arr = $xml->toArray();
        $status = trim(current(Set::extract('/Response/status', $arr)));
        if ($status != 'ok') {
            $err = current(Set::extract('/Response/error', $arr));
            if (empty($err)) {
                $err = 'An unknown error occurred.';
            }
            throw new Exception(__d('freshbooks', $err, true));
            return false;
        }
        return $arr;
    }

/**
 * _formatResponse
 * All keys in array lowercase and
 * blank arrays become ''
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @param integer $skip
 * @return array
 */
    protected function _formatResponse(&$data=null, $skip=2) {
        if ($skip == 0) {
            $data = array_change_key_case($data, CASE_LOWER);
        } else {
            $skip--;
        }
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                if (sizeof($val) == 0) {
                    $data[$key] = '';
                } else {
                    $this->_formatResponse($data[$key], $skip);
                }
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * listSources
 * @return boolean
 */
    public function listSources() {
        return false;
    }

/**
 * describe
 *
 * @param object $model
 * @return array
 */
    public function describe(&$model) {
        if (isset($model->schema)) {
            return $model->schema;
        } else {
            return array('id' => array());
        }
    }

/**
* calculate
* Just return $func to give read() the field 'count'
*
* @param Model $model
* @param mixed $func
* @param array $params
* @return array
* @access public
*/
    public function calculate(&$model, $func, $params=array()) {
        return $func;
    }

/**
 * __getAuthArray
 * @return array
 */
    private function __getAuthArray() {
        return array(
            'auth' => array(
                'method' => 'Basic',
                'user' => $this->config['token'],
                'pass' => 'X',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to read the error message? It is more than obvious:

> Call to undefined method Xml::toString()

[The core XML class](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Xml.html) has no `toString()` method nor [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring). So this code is wrong for whatever reason.